# Custom data not persisting in DWG file after closing AutoCAD session

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm currently working on an AutoCAD API project where I need to store custom data in a DWG file using Named Objects Dictionary. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the custom data is not persisting in the file after the AutoCAD session is closed.

Please note that i am saving the document after adding the custom data. Although the custom data persists when I only close the document and reopen it, it doesn't seem to survive when I close the entire AutoCAD application.

I'm wondering if anyone in the community has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions for how to resolve this problem. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice you can provide.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using COMMIT?

Comment: Share sample code please.